# How to print code128C?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to print a code128C (numbers only) but I believe that the way of sending the data is incorrect ... at the time of reading the code the conversion does not result in the data initially informed.

In code128A I submit an ASCCI code, the printer converts to hex and print...the reader convert it back to ASCII.
In code128C if I submit an ASCCI, at the time of reading the reader converts to decimal, which does not result in the initial value.

EX:

- 128A Input: '1' Printer: 31 Reading: 1
- 128C Input: '1' Printer: 31 Reading: 49

I imagine that I should submit the input code already in integer .... but as the command is composed of other information I do not know how to send it in integer.

This is the code of code128A:

```
ComandoAnsiString := tp.cod128A('12'); //Data entry

function TTP650.cod128A(cod: AnsiString): AnsiString;
begin 
  // Fill out the CODE 128 printing protocol     
  Result := #29+#107+#73 + chr(length(cod)+2) + #123+#65 + cod;         
end;

WritePrinter( HandleImp, PAnsiChar(ComandoAnsiString), Length(ComandoAnsiString), 
              CaracteresImpressos);  //send to printer
```

This is the code I've been trying with code128C:

```
ComandoAnsiString := tp.cod128C('12');

function TTP650.cod128C(cod: AnsiString): AnsiString;
begin      
  Result := #29+#107+#73 + chr(length(cod)+2) + #123+#67 + cod;     
end;

WritePrinter( HandleImp, PAnsiChar(ComandoAnsiString), Length(ComandoAnsiString), 
              CaracteresImpressos);
```

I'm dealing with a thermal printer and one codebar reader simple, default.
The sending codes(WritePrinter) are from the library `WinSpool` ... the rest are codes written by me.

Important code information is on pages 47 to 50 of the guide.

[Guide](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kkw9LQYPA8G7P50Vvp7elMbiximDDAUN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `"The printer"` ...what printer? `"the reader"` ...what reader?  Remember that we have no idea what you are working on, what printer is on your desk, or anything else about what software libraries they may have provided that you might be using, or what code you've shown us belongs to that library and what code you've written yourself.  This needs more detail to answer.

Comment: With that said, the character `1` (symbol for the number one) has a decimal ascii value of `49` and a hex representation of `0x31`.  It would seem that you are confusing the character itself, its ascii value in decimal, and its ascii value in hex.  Without more information it is difficult to say where.

Comment: `I'm dealing with a thermal printer (Dot-Matrix)`  It's either thermal OR dot matrix, not both.  For barcodes, we can expect it is a thermal printer of some sort.  What is important is to know the make and model of the printer - if you're using `WritePrinter` you need to know what format the printer is expecting to receive.  We can't know what that is if you don't tell us what printer you are using.

Comment: With that said... it's 2019.  We have printer drivers now.  If trawling through WinAPI is giving you grief, just get a Code128C font and print using high level functions instead.  Life doesn't need to be so difficult...

Comment: @J...The printer receives the data in the format I have specified in CommandAnsiString ...
"# 29 + # 107 + # 73 + chr (length (codigo) +2) + # 123 + # 67 + codigo"
but this does not influence the questioning ... I have no doubts about it.The problem is that code is sent along with the other information in AnsiString format (characters) and I think that an integer should be sent.How to do?

Comment: @Joelend, if you could add an extract from the manual that describes the command you want to send, I'm sure you can get help from here.

Comment: @LURD follow the guide as requested.

Comment: @KenWhite I posted the command line in the question itself, where it was judged not enough and asked for an excerpt from the guide... that's what I did.
I ask you to comment if you can add something to the problem, otherwise, if you think you should not read, do not read.

Comment: Not the way it works, either. You don't get to decide who can and cannot read or comment on your posts here, and users do the majority of moderation on this site. I'll refer you again to the [help/on-topic] guidelines, especially the [tour], which explains how the site works. An *excerpt from the guide* is not *a link to another site and a list of the specific 4 pages of the manual you should read*.

Comment: @KenWhite I had already posted an excerpt from the manual ... and I can not submit images ... I do not see any other way of subordering the manual. At no point did I say that I decide on who can or can not read, it was you who said that you will not read ... I just did not see what your information "I will not read" contributes to the question ... but you can comment on the will.
I kindly ask you to keep your focus on the problem and as it says in the guidelines you sent me "Remember: we're all here to learn, so be friendly and helpful!"

Comment: WritePrinter takes a pointer to an array of bytes as input.  I would avoid using `PAnsiChar` in place of `TBytes` if you really want bytes.  String types sometimes do odd things to non-printable bytes.

Comment: @Joelend, the link to the docs is fine, but the question needs to stand on its own. That was why I asked to include the essence of the documentation into the question. The format of this Q/A site can take some learning. Don't mistake pointers for unfriendlyness or unhelpfulness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming users will enter the wanted barcodes as a string of digits which may be stored somewhere as string and at the time of printing, passed to the printing function as human readable string.

The printing function will then convert to an array of bytes, packing the digits according to CODE C (each pair of two decimal digits, forming a value 00..99, stored in a byte). Iow, if the entry string of digits is e.g. '123456', then this is represented by three bytes with values 12, 34, 56.

```
function cod128C(const cod: string): TBytes;
const
  GS =  29;  // GS - Print bar code
   k = 107;  //  k -     -"-
   m =  73;  //  m - CODE128
  CS = 123;  //  { - select code set //}
  CC =  67;  //  C - CODE C
var
  i, len, n, x: integer;
  s: string;
begin
  len := Length(cod);
  if len = 0 then exit;
  // raise for odd number of digits in cod, ...
  // if Odd(len) then
  //   raise Exception.Create('cod must have even number of digits');

  s := cod;

  // ... alternatively assume a preceeding zero digit before the first digit
  // in cod
  if Odd(len) then
  begin
    s := '0'+s;
    inc(len);
  end;

  len := len div 2; // we pack 2 digits into one byte

  SetLength(result, 6 + len);

  result[0] := GS;
  result[1] := k;
  result[2] := m;
  result[3] := 2 + len;   // length of cod, + 2 for following code set selector
  result[4] := CS;        
  result[5] := CC;        

  n := length(s);

  i := 1;  // index to S
  x := 6;  // index to result

  while i < n do
  begin
    result[x] := StrToInt(MidStr(s, i, 2));
    inc(i, 2);
    inc(x, 1);
  end;

end;
```

And with a form with a button, edit and memo you can test the function and send it to your printer with the following.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  cmnd: TBytes;
  i: integer;
  s: string;
begin
  cmnd := cod128C(Edit1.Text);

  for i := 0 to Length(cmnd)-1 do
    s := s+IntToStr(cmnd[i])+', ';
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);

  WritePrinter( HandleImp, @cmnd[0], Length(cmnd), CaracteresImpressos);
end;
```

You may want to add a check for only decimal digits in the input string, but I leave that to you.